# Do linearly independent polynomials over number fields have linearly independent coordinates over the rationals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$.
Suppose $\{1, p_1, \dots, p_k\} \subseteq K[x]$ is a linearly independent family (over $K$).

Let $\{b_1, b_2, \dots, b_d\}$ be an integral basis in $\mathcal{O}_K$.
For each $i=1, \dots, k$, let $p_{i,1}, \dots, p_{i,d} \in \mathbb{Q}[x_1, \dots, x_d]$ be the coordinate polynomials of $p_i$, i.e.

\begin{align}
 p_i \left( \sum_{j=1}^d{x_jb_j} \right) = \sum_{j=1}^d{p_{i,j}(x_1, \dots, x_d)b_j}
\end{align}

for $x_1, \dots, x_d \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Is the family $\{1\} \cup \{p_{i,j} : 1 \le i \le k, 1 \le j \le d\} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[x_1, \dots, x_d]$ linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$?

**Example**

A simple example, for which the answer is "yes", is $K = \mathbb{Q}(i)$ with the polynomials $p_1(x) = x$ and $p_2(x) = x^2$.
In the integral basis $\{1, i\}$, we can expand

\begin{align}
p_1(x_1 + ix_2) & = x_1 + ix_2 \\
p_2(x_1 + ix_2) & = (x_1^2 - x_2^2) + i(2x_1x_2),
\end{align}

so $p_{1,1}(x_1,x_2) = x_1$, $p_{1,2}(x_1,x_2) = x_2$, $p_{2,1}(x_1,x_2) = x_1^2 - x_2^2$, and $p_{2,2}(x_1,x_2) = 2x_1x_2$.

For this example, the set $\{1, p_{1,1}, p_{1,2}, p_{2,1}, p_{2,2}\} = \{1, x_1, x_2, x_1^2 - x_2^2, 2x_1x_2\}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Does the integrality of the basis $\{b_j\}$ play any role here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you’ve made things difficult for yourself by stressing the ring structure of $K[x]$. Let me rather look at your question and your example in a different light, purely as a question in linear algebra.

Your choice of polynomials, $x$ and $x^2$, makes up a linearly independent set over $K$, in the $K$-vector space $K[x]$. You ask whether $(1x, ix, 1x^2, ix^2)$, as an ordered quadruple, forms a $\Bbb Q$-linearly independent set in the $\Bbb Q$-vector space $K[x]$. Looked at in this way, I think you say, “Of course”, since if $\lambda_1\cdot1x+\lambda_2ix+\lambda_3\cdot1x^2+\lambda_4ix^2=0$, then we have a statement of complex linear dependence $(\lambda_1+i\lambda_2)x+(\lambda_3+i\lambda_4)x^2=0$.

I was going to go into greater detail, looking at $K[x]$ as a tensor product
$K[x]\cong K\otimes_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb Q[x]$, but I don’t have time. If you’d like to see this, say so in a comment and I’ll get to it later.

Comment: Thanks! The polynomials $\{b_jp_i\} = \{1x, ix, 1x^2, ix^2\}$ aren't exactly the ones I'm considering, but the polynomials $p_{i,j}$ are linear combinations of their real parts (or in general, the $b_1$-coordinate), so this idea seems to work.

Comment: If I have time,  I’ll try to absorb your concept of coordinate polynomials—I confess I assumed that the tensor-product approach was equivalent to yours.